# Fomat Widget Expressions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, format, numbering, leading-zero

I want something basic; like I do in excel or access. The user enters a value and excel formats it. If it's a phone number and I want it in '####-#######' format; or if it is a number and I want to pad some zeros in it. So, if the user enters 123, it automatically pads a '0' and enters the data 0123; and for a two-digit number it adds two leading zeros. It also allows me to add some prefix to a 'number data type'. There's a suffix option though. But there should be some tools to dynamically set the format as user want.

[image]

We have constraints and default option but I found no way to format the field features automatically as user(field worker/surveyor) enters the value convenient to him. We can do this in excel, or access or any database. As, the table here is also representing a database so there should be a formatting option. We cannot trust field users to enter the structured data, but in databases, data should be consistent and structured.

In this case, for a pocket ID; I want to add "STP", as a prefix. I can do this with 'concat' or || operator in **default** field. It works this time, but for leading zeros case I'm not able to make something more functional. So, is there something more generic in QGIS for formatting?
[image]

Comment: It is unclear to me, what you mean by "dynamically set the format as user want".

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply. I forgot to turn the notifications on. Like if there's a dash or brackets in expression. Like in American phone number format... I just want to format the number like if field worker enters 123456789, it format it as (123)-456789; or if he enter 123 the QGIS format it as 0123 to maintain the database structure. Dynamic means, if I want some word; like prefix at start or in between some text field; I can format it as I want.

Comment: @Erik; as another example you can also interpret it like - if the user enters 10, the attribute table saves some value after an arithmetic operation. Like "Field"*10, would return 100 in this case.

Comment: Be careful that formatting has different meaning : you could format the display (ie. just how the value is presented) or you can format the "real value" (ie. how the value is stored). For exemple in excel you could choose different format to display a value  but the data itself are not changed in any way. This has implication on witch data type your data will be stored (for exemple a number will be stored (or has to be stored) as text if you input it with space, but you can keep it stored as a number if you only display it with space)

Comment: @J.R, Yeah, that's true... So, I have managed it by separating the datatypes; instead of writing STP02 now, there'll be two fields, a text field with 'STP' and a numeric field with 02. Now, I'm facing the problem of adding leading zeros to it. So, if user enters 2; table should store 02. The formatting problem of phone numbers in (123)-456789 format is also not cleared. I'm not sure if some generic functionality exists for this or not.

Comment: You can't have leading 0 in a numeric field to store '02' you need a text field...

Comment: I think the easiest way for you is to have some "input" editable field where people type value and some "formated" (non editable) field filled by a formula based on the input field (this could be automated by imputing the formula as default value)